# Copy file to a network share with different username and password

Tags: perl

I was wondering of this is possible in Perl

I want to access a network file share (NT) to copy a file using different username and password

This perl script is part of build and will be running in server without any user interaction

Thanks

Karthik

Comment: I can solve this problem as described here

http://serverfault.com/questions/353376/mapping-network-share-with-different-credentials/353380#353380

Answer (score 2):

This post on [perlmonks](http://www.perlmonks.org) seems to cover that topic: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=491533

[`Win32::NetResource`](http://search.cpan.org/~jdb/Win32-NetResource-0.056/NetResource.pm) has an `AddConnection` function that you could pass `USERNAME` and `PASSWORD` to.